# Why does FileHandle::getpos on a newly-opened handle return the empty string rather than 0?

Tags: perl, file-io

I'm trying to use `getpos` in Perl. I am using a `FileHandle` object in the code below, and it doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use FileHandle;

my $fh = new FileHandle;
$fh->open("<test.txt") or die "$!";
my $pos = $fh->getpos;
print "pos: \"$pos\"\n";
```

The output is:

```
pos: ""
```

I would expect "0" to be output...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the caveat (emphasis added) in the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/FileHandle.html):

> If the C functions `fgetpos` and `fsetpos` are available, then **`FileHandle::getpos` returns an opaque value** that represents the current position of the `FileHandle`, and `FileHandle::setpos` uses that value to return to a previously visited position.

Opaque means you shouldn't pay attention the value: use it only as a parameter in future requests from the module.

Why not use Perl's [`tell`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tell.html) and [`seek`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) operators?

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh, "<", $0 or die "$0: open: $!";
print tell($fh), "\n";
```

The output of the above program is `0`, as you expect.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for FileHandle says that the value returned by `getpos` is an opaque value which means that in general you cannot assume anything meaningful about the value. The only thing it's good for is passing back to `setpos`. This matches the underlying system calls used to implement the method (fgetpos and fsetpos) which are represented in C as opaque `fpos_t` pointers. The `seek` and `tell` methods if available use integer file positions that can be manipulated.